# Number of solutions of exponential equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can anyone tell me how to find number of solutions $(x+a)^x=b$? For example $(x+1)^x=-1$ has four complex solutions, $(x+3)^x=10$ has two solutions,one positive one negative, and $(x-4)^x=-10$ hasn't any solutions.

PS.Sorry for my bad English,I hope you understand my question.

Comment: Is there anything that makes you think there is a nice form for the number of solutions?

Comment: This is probably related to the Lambert W function. Wikipedia has a pretty good article on this object.

Comment: @JoshuaCiappara I think you're right, but the details escape me, the main point is $x$ ends up showing as a reciprocal where the Lambert formula seems to need it as just $x$ modulo some multiplicative constant.

Answer (score 1):

How to solve $(x+a)^x=b$?

Well, to begin, as you already gather, we must allow for $x \in \mathbb{C}$. Then the question begs the question how do we define $z^x$ for complex $x$. Use the complex exponential function:
$$ z^x = \exp (x \log (z)) $$
clearly $z=0$ is a problem. Moreover, this is a set of values due to the fact that $\log (z)$ is multiply valued. Consider then, $(x+a)^x=b$ becomes:
$$ \exp (x \log (x+a)) =b $$
If $b \neq 0$ then it follows that,
$$ x \log (x+a) = \log b $$
Assume $x \neq 0$ and divide by $x$,
$$  \log (x+a) = \frac{1}{x}\log b. $$
Exponentiate, note $\exp (\log (z))=z$ 
$$  x+a = \exp \left( \frac{1}{x}\log b \right). $$
This is clearly transcendental, perhaps that was clear from the outset. But, at best we can hope to characterize solutions with a special function. Perhaps the Lambert W-function. According to (1) under "Generalizations" in the Wikipedia article,
$$ e^{-cx} = a_o(x-r) $$
has solution
$$ x = r + \frac{1}{c} \text{W} \left( \frac{ce^{-cr}}{a_o} \right)$$
This is lovely, but $e^{-cx}$ should look more like $e^{c/x}$ to match the problem we face. Perhaps a champion of the Lambert-$W$ function will appear and show us the light.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I don't understand. So, $a_0=1$,$c=-\ln b$,$r = -a$; But there is 1/x in  $\exp \left( \frac{1}{x}\log b \right)$and x in the left side of $e^{-cx} = a_o(x-r)$.

Comment: Ok, propably i find the solution.

Comment: I haven't found a solution either, I merely showed that I can't see how it fits the Lambert-W-function.